# Rails help creating redirecting action and route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a route and a action that redirects the params.

Example when a user visits: `www.mywebsite.com/photographer/flv/:ID/:filename`

I want the user to be redirected to:  `www.someotherwebsite.com/photographer/flv/:ID/:filename`

I have tried to accomplish with this solution without luck:

My controller URL:

```
def videore
redirect_to www.whateverwebsite.com + params[:all] 
end
```

And in routes:

```
match '/photographer/flv/:ID/:filename' => 'URL#videore'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

In your controller action:

```
def videore
  redirect_to "http://www.whateverwebsite.com/photographer/flv/#{params[:id]}/#{params[:filename]}"
end
```

And in routes:

```
match '/photographer/flv/:id/:filename' => 'url#videore'
```

This assumes, of course, that 'url' is the name of your controller

Comment: Is it not possiable to make a injection?

Comment: As far as I'm aware - and I'm not entirely certain of this - there's no functionality in a redirect_to string that can do any more damage than entering the same string manually into the URL bar. If this were touching the database it would be a concern, but a redirect_to should (I think) be safe.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Ruby on Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection):

```
match "/stories/:name" => redirect("/posts/%{name}")
```

> In all of these cases, if you don’t provide the leading host
>   (http://www.example.com), Rails will take those details from the
>   current request.

So redirecting to another TLD should work like this (no action in your controller required):

```
match '/photographer/flv/:ID/:filename' => redirect("http://www.someotherwebsite.com/photographer/flv/%{ID}/%{filename}")
```

Comment: Did you have a chance to try this, yet?